# Powershell copy folder and exclude one file at root level

Tags: powershell, copy

Let's say I have the following folder structure:

```
C:\Source\file1.txt
C:\Source\file2.txt
C:\Source\file3.txt
C:\Source\more\file1.txt
C:\Source\more\file4.txt

C:\Destination\file1.txt
C:\Destination\file2.txt
C:\Destination\file3.txt
C:\Destination\more\file1.txt
C:\Destination\more\file4.txt
```

I am trying to write a PowerShell script which copies everything from the Source folder to the Destination folder, except the file `C:\Source\file1.txt`. The file `C:\Source\more\file1.txt` should still be copied.

I tried it with this command:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\" -Exclude "C:\Destination\file1.txt" -Recurse -Force
```

But the `Exclude` parameter apparently doesn't accept absolute paths. And if I just do this:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source\" -Exclude "file1.txt" -Recurse -Force
```

Then the file in `C:\Source\more\file1.txt` will also be excluded. But this file should be copied, only `file1.txt` located in the `Source` folder should be skipped.

Comment: Are you looking to keep the folder structure?

Comment: Yes, the structure should stay intact.

Answer (score 0):

This function can do the same as `Copy-Item` but can exclude files and folders based on expressions passed as arguments to the `-ExcludeExpression`. The expressions are passed in the form of a [`Script Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.3) and can take multiple filtering expressions. I won't go much into details with the code because it's fairly complex.

```
function Copy-Stuff {
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Path', Mandatory, Position = 0, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]] $Path,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPath', Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]] $LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
        [string] $Destination,

        [Parameter()]
        [scriptblock[]] $ExcludeExpression,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $Recurse,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $Force,

        [Parameter()]
        [string] $Filter = '*'
    )

    begin {
        $stack = [Collections.Generic.Stack[IO.FileSystemInfo]]::new()
        $Destination = $PSCmdlet.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Destination)
    }
    process {
        $isLiteral = $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('LiteralPath')
        $paths     = $Path
        if($isLiteral) {
            $paths = $LiteralPath
        }

        foreach($item in $ExecutionContext.InvokeProvider.Item.Get($paths, $true, $isLiteral)) {
            if($item.FullName -eq $Destination) {
                continue
            }

            $stack.Push($item)

            $here = $item.Parent.FullName
            if($item -is [IO.FileInfo]) {
                $here = $item.Directory.FullName
            }

            :outer while($stack.Count) {
                $item = $stack.Pop()
                foreach($expression in $ExcludeExpression) {
                    if($expression.InvokeWithContext($null, [psvariable]::new('_', $item))) {
                        continue outer
                    }
                }

                $to = Join-Path $Destination -ChildPath $item.FullName.Replace($here, '')

                if($item -is [IO.DirectoryInfo]) {
                    $null = [IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($to)

                    if($Recurse.IsPresent) {
                        try {
                            $enum = $item.EnumerateFileSystemInfos($Filter)
                        }
                        catch {
                            $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
                            continue
                        }
                    }

                    foreach($child in $enum) {
                        $stack.Push($child)
                    }
                    continue
                }

                try {
                    $null = $item.CopyTo($to, $Force.IsPresent)
                }
                catch {
                    if($_.Exception.InnerException -is [IO.DirectoryNotFoundException]) {
                        $null = [IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory([IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($to))
                        continue
                    }
                    $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

##### How should you use it?

The asterisk `*` after source signals that you want to **copy all files and folders inside `source` but not copy `source` itself**.

The expression `{ $_.FullName.EndsWith('\Source\file1.txt') }` should be changed accordingly, and multiple expressions can be added. In this case, it will exclude **any file or folder which's absolute path ends with `\Source\file1.txt`**.

```
Copy-Stuff .\source\* -Destination .\destination -ExcludeExpression {
    $_.FullName.EndsWith('\Source\file1.txt')
} -Recurse
```